# Error connectiong to SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Im gettng a "Failed to establish connection." when I click design in the bottom right (see image provided). I've been searching like hell but cant figure it out. Its the same for all three databases. They seem to work fine using the applications that uses them(except one thing I want to check out though). Any ideas or even better- answers :) ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen above is accesible from the subscription account and I would have had to log in with the Azure SQL account for it to work. I didn´t even know it existed but Azure Microsoft support found the solution after a couple of emails.. Great support service I must say!

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this. I'm sure that I'm logging into the Managment Portal with my correct SQL credentials, but its still giving me the same error. :(

Comment: @Kevin Hicks Do you have two '@' in your login name? Mine look like this: john.doe@outlook.com@kweqnlo3w6 The last number is your server name

Answer (score 1):

Is the PC you are working from added to the firewall list for the database server? That's the most common reason. If the 'App' you are referring to is an Azure app then you will not have the problem, as the azure infrastructure is within the firewall.

And if your IP changes all the time you are going to have to repeat this (or open up a range of IPs).

If you're not sure, go to the Azure portal, select "SQL Databases", then the "server" option, then the "Manage" button at the bottom. If your IP is not in the firewall ruleset you will get a message like that below [sorry - no image - apparently I'm a new user and not allowed to be that helpful]. Select the tick and you'll be right to go.

Phil.

Comment: My IP is added to the firewall list. Without it I would not be able to browse my application. The service connectig to the databse is a web role. It uses the database fine but I just cant use the "summary" and "design" buttons without this error.